# Styles added to control working on online server, not on local wamp server

Tags: php, css, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

The project designer added some styles to the cakephp form control. Those are working fine on the remote server. When we downloaded all the code and testing them on the local development WAMP server, those are not get added in the webpage. Why would this happen?

The code designer added for styles is as follows.

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('style'=>'width:80px;', 'class' => 'mycontrol'));
```

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Can you add the html code produced by that line?

Comment: Sounds unlikely you're running the same code on the server and wamp - inline styles don't magically disappear (though, they should).